# Get the latest inserted id in a trigger?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I use a trigger to insert a row and want to use the last created id for using in the subsequent query.

How could I do this?

The code looks like:

```
BEGIN
IF (NEW.counter >= 100) THEN
INSERT INTO tagCategories (name, counter) VALUES ('unnamed', NEW.counter);
// here i want to have access to the above inserted id
UPDATE tagCategories2tagPairs SET tagCategoryId = <<ID_HERE>> WHERE tagPairId = OLD.id
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)? But be aware:

> If you insert multiple rows using a
>   single INSERT statement,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value
>   generated for the first inserted row
>   only.

Comment: When I use this in an after_trigger, it returns the previous inserted ID for some reason... e.g. `NEW.id` can be used though. And e.g. `OLD.id` can be used on delete or update (at least this is what is written in the docs.). [docs.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: @ravo10 Exactly, one should use the NEW and OLD objects to avoid the issue with multiple row insertions instead of LAST_INSERT_ID(). This is shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5041618/1153801).

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to use a company initials like "AAA" and add the insert ID to it and use it as a internal company ID and this is how I picked up the last current insert ID

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER company_run_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON ap_company 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

SET @lastID = (SELECT id FROM ap_company ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
IF @lastID IS NULL OR @lastID = '' THEN
    SET @lastID = 0;
END IF;
SET @lastID = @lastID +1;
SET NEW.ap_company_id = concat(NEW.company_initials,'-', @lastID);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the index of the inserted row from the server (the loop index)
and in the trigger "before insert" you can do the following :

```
BEGIN
if (NEW.id=0) then
set @A = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
     FROM information_schema.TABLES
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "schema"
    AND TABLE_NAME = "table");
    end if;
SET NEW.id  = NEW.id + @A ;
END
```

let we assume that LAST_INSERT_ID() = 5

and you are trying to add 3 rows at the same insert statement ...

so , the first row would have 5 + 0

second : 5 + 1

third : 5 + 2

Answer (score -1):

USE NEW.id

```
BEGIN
insert INTO test_questions (test_id, question, variant1, variant2, variant3, w1, type_id) 
SELECT NEW.id, t1.question, t1.v1, t1.v2, t1.v3, t1.answer, 1
FROM new_minitest_questions t1
WHERE t1.mt_id = NEW.old_id;
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Following trigger will get the last Auto Increment value from the Information Schema. I had written this trigger to generate a slug.

For instances, if the column's name is "Name" and column has a value such as "Robin Shankar", the trigger would replace spaces with "-" and also append the Auto Increment Id to the end of the slug, hence making a unique slug.

**robin_shankar_9071**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_slug_sd
BEFORE INSERT ON `your_table_name`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE auto_increment_ INT(11);

SELECT 
    `auto_increment` 
INTO 
    auto_increment_
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE 
table_name = 'your_table_name';

SET NEW.`Slug` = CONCAT(LOWER(REPLACE(NEW.`Name`,' ','-')),'-',auto_increment_);
END; //

DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SET NEW.num=CONCAT("А-", (
  SELECT `auto_increment` 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES    
  WHERE table_name = 'menu')
)
```

Comment: max(id) and so on is don't work if you are delete a last records