# How to get last inserted row ID from wordpress database with trigger which increment ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, triggers

I use Wordpress with a database. My problem is that I want to retrieve the inserted ID when using `wpdb-> insert`. I want to clarify that I increment the ID using a database trigger because my table is a relative entity. I was thinking of creating a procedure that I would call after my insertion.

My trigger

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE num INTEGER;
  IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
    SET num =  
    (
      SELECT MAX(id) + 1
      FROM ab_autreFrais
      WHERE idDevis = NEW.idDevis
    );
    SET NEW.id = num;
  ELSEIF NEW.id = 0 THEN
    SET num = 
    (
      SELECT MAX(id) + 1
      FROM ab_autreFrais
      WHERE idDevis = NEW.idDevis
    );
    SET NEW.id = num;
  END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function that you can use instead of the trigger. Also you can get this value through an output parameter of a stored procrdure.
Or you could use auxiliary table or a global variable to put `id` value from the trigger. For example:

```
... 
SET NEW.id = num;
UPDATE `SysData` SET `LastID` = num;
...
```

Comment: Yes i could use last_insert_id but the id of table don't use auto increment. Also i can't create prodecedure from my database

Comment: @labardass, oh,  I'm sorry! But why don't you want to use autoincrement column?

Comment: Because i would like make a relative entity, do you know the relative entity?

Comment: @labardass, I never used relative entities.

Comment: i think find a solution to my problem. i go used a select for get the max id and add 1 at this id

Comment: The relative entities of the MERISE method is a conceptual database method. It is not very used but I learned like that the database

Comment: @labardass, I can propose only use auxiliary table or variable if it is possible. See my updated answer for details or https://stackoverflow.com/a/5041618/7914637

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander
``` UPDATE ``SysData`` SET ``LastID`` = num; ``` Does not work on MySQL SysData is not exist. I used `SET SESSION last_insert_id = num` in sql on phpmyadmin it work but with wpdb when i call `last_insert_id()` it return 0