# Mysql trigger to insert on two connected tables

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have 3 mysql tables:

**user_followers** has columns id,user_id
**notification** has columns id,user_id
**notification_object** has columns notification_id , type

On insert on user_followers i want to insert

user_id=New.user_id in notification

and then using the id of notification just inserted

notification_object.type = "2" and notification_object.notification_id = just inserted id in notifcication table

now the problem is how can i find the id of notifcation table:

```
DELIMITER //


CREATE TRIGGER follow_notification AFTER INSERT ON user_friends
FOR EACH ROW 
Begin
insert into notification(user_id) values(New.user_id);
insert into notification_object(notification_id,type) values(????,"2");

End

//
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the latest inserted id in a trigger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263453/get-the-latest-inserted-id-in-a-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

if `notifications.id` is auto-incremented, mysql includes a function `last_insert_id()` that will return ([with caveats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21188)) the lastly inserted id.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER follow_notification AFTER INSERT ON user_friends
FOR EACH ROW 
Begin
  declare v_notification_id INT;
  insert into notification(user_id) values(New.user_id);
  /* set a variable to the last id inserted to the db */
  set v_notification_id=(select last_insert_id());
  /* use the variable in the next insert */
  insert into notification_object(notification_id,type) values(v_notification_id,"2");

End//
```