# Mysql trigger, set id from a new insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I need some help creating a trigger (i think this is the solution)
Imagine i have 2 tables:

character

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | stat_id |             
+----+------+---------+
|    |      |         |
+----+------+---------+
```

and

stats

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | ...  | char_id |             
+----+------+---------+
|    |      |         |
+----+------+---------+
```

So...
I made an trigger to create a new row on the stats table, after i made a new insert in the character table:

```
TRIGGER `new_stats_after_charcreation` AFTER INSERT ON `character` FOR EACH `ROW INSERT INTO stats (char_id) VALUES (new.id)`
```

this way, when i register a new character, the trigger will insert a new row in the stats table with the character id on "char_id"

but the question is, what can i do to update the "stat_id" field in the character table with the new id generated from the trigger?

Hope you guys understand, sorry for my bad english!
Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think this is possible via trigger, but you probably don't need a two way link between them. What is the relationship between the two tables (1:1,1:n,n:1) ?

Comment: 1:1 can you please help me out? haha, i'm not that good with sql

Comment: How many stats does a character have and/or how many characters does a stat have (by stat i mean 1 row in the stats table)?

Comment: the 1:1 was correct haha, 1 stats row for each character row

Comment: In that case you only need a one way link (either char_id in stats or stat_id in characters). Also you might as well put the stats in the characters table, and avoid the trouble of auto generating deleting and updating the linked rows.

Comment: hmmmmmm now i see, you are right! cleared my mind haha
Thank you very much o/

Answer (score 0):

As commenters pointed out, you don't need it. The 1:1 relation can be replaced by fusion of the two tables. But for the completeness, here are two basic hints.

1. Use BEFORE INSERT trigger, not AFTER, so you can manipulate foreign table id before you write the data.
2. Use LAST_INSERTED_ID() to get and use the inserted id in the foreign table (read [Get the latest inserted id in a trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2263453/4711098) for further information)