# AUTO_INCREMENT in mysql can be signed by default?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, unsigned, signed

i understand,below `column` will be `signed int` by default.

```
   id INT(6);
```

Can an `auto increment column` specified below be signed by default? Mysql starts the value from 1 for an auto increment column.

```
id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: Why you do not try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create an auto increment primary key with a signed int. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable( id int(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then the following queries are both valid

```
INSERT INTO mytable values();
INSERT INTO mytable values(-10);
```

This will result in the table having a row with -10 and another with 1 as values. But you will run into problems if you try this:

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT=-10;
```

yes, you cannot have auto increment values that are negative numbers.

Comment: And what about make a TRIGGER that takes the id and add minus on it after INSERT ? Is it possible ?

Comment: yes, possible but you are playing with fire. if you are going to multiply the generated id by -1 that would be safe @Meloman

Comment: Mutiply by -1 safer than CONCAT('-', id) ? interesting... I made an example working for me here under https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802856/2282880 what are you thinking about ?

Comment: you said 'add minus on it' which sounds like arithmatic addition.

Comment: Yes sorry, my english is baaaaad ! I concat a dash wich is the same on my keyboard as minus right ? :)

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searches... I looked for a solution with a TRIGGER called BEFORE INSERT ! I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43441586/2282880

Here is my variant :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `invertID` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `<table>`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.id=CONCAT("-", (
        SELECT `auto_increment` 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES    
        WHERE table_name = '<table>')
    )
```

It worked for me fine.

It was the best way I found to sync in both directions two databases with same schema without same ID's in my tables.

Comment: **NOTE:** This doesn't work if you want to `insert` two or more rows at once (`INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES 
(...), (...), (...);`). ***MySQL said: #1062 - Duplicate entry '-n' for key 'x'***.